# how to use angular expression with django template - href url

Tags: angularjs, django-templates, django-urls, angularjs-interpolate

I have following code in my django template :

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="(key, value) in products" style=" ">
    <a href="{% url 'appname:productdetail' 150 %}" class="icon">View</a>
</li>
```

here 150 is value.id which i would access as {$value.id$} as I am using interpolate provider.

but I can't write something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'appname:productdetail' {$value.id$} %}" class="icon">View</a>
```

as it is npot valid for template.

I am stuck that how I can create URL in template using angular expression.
Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to put your url in your controller, and append it with `value.id` in your view

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I have found so far:

```
<a href="{% url 'appname:productdetail' ''%}{$value.id$}/" class="icon">View</a>
```

In some cases it can work without empty quotes.